# To which timezone does the "date" in Gmail refer?

Tags: gmail, time-zone

I use Gmail for my email. I do not understand to which point in time the "date" of an email in Gmail refers: is this the local time when/where I received the email, or is it the local time when/from where the mail has been sent?

Is the "date" of an email, as shown by Gmail, local time of the sender or receiver?

Is it from the moment where it has been sent or received?

Comment: in genral you could find what timezone which you are using at under personalization tab of gmail

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Gmail shows you the time when a message was sent, based on your local time zone. So the time
shown is your local time, not the sender's local time when the message
was sent

Comment: It might be helpful to note that `Google Mail` stores the UTC time when the email was actually recieved.  They translate this to your local time zone using a combination methods.  By doing this the time is always correct for any user.

Comment: Can I make a datetime filter on google mail  in UTC time zone? I am using Gmail API

Comment: @ShmuelKamensky - No